# JPA Native Query doesn't seem to support PostgreSQL ARRAY function

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

My query is:

```
SELECT id
FROM person
WHERE authority_right = ARRAY[1,2]
```

`authority_right` is integer array. My goal is to find people who have
`authority_right` exactly equal to [1,2], not [1] and not [2]. This query is executed successfully in console, but a validation error occurs when I launch my application with `@Query` using the exact same code.
Error occurs in this area: `ARRAY[1,2]`.
Message in logs:

```
expecting CLOSE_BRACKET, found ','
```

Message in editor:

```
<expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got '{'
```

I also tried using `INT{1, 2}` and some combinations of brackets, but I haven't succeed. How can I make it work?

Comment: `right` is a reserved keyword. So you need double quotes: `where "right" = ...`. If you are using a native query in JPQL, the `ARRAY[...]` syntax should work. Alternatively use a string constant for the array `where "right" = '{1,2}'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm sorry for confusion, the field name is actually `authority_right`, I shortened it intentionally in the question. I've tried your suggestion `where "right" = '{1,2}'`, unfortunately it produces another validation error `person is not mapped`